# recvfrom() on a UDP socket returns -1 but WSAGetLastError() returns 0

Tags: c++, sockets

I can't seem to figure out why this is happening. I'm not using any socket library that could be calling WSAGetLastError(), because I'm only using the C socket functions on a Windows platform. I am using select() to manage multiple UDP sockets, so perhaps that has something to do with it. Here's what's going on:

I have many UDP sockets that I register with a fd_set and use select() to check only when read operations are available. I iterate through all my sockets and check FD_ISSET() to make sure a read operation is available. I then make the call to recvfrom() which seems to work the majority of the time, but occasionally when there is a flurry of activity on one of the sockets, recvfrom() will return -1. When I make the subsequent call to WSAGetLastError(), it returns 0 (and this is the only call to WSAGetLastError in my entire application). If I ignore the error, the socket continues to function normally. It's able to recv data still and do its thing. It's just very strange.

I know it's possible for a UDP socket to return 0 (a valid empty UDP packet) which is not the case for TCP (clean shutdown), but could -1 also be normal possibly? I thought perhaps this was being caused by some kind of a concurrency issue, where one thread may be performing a sendto() on a socket while recvfrom() is in the process of being called, so I added a mutex to prevent this from occuring (yet the behavior is still present).

I'm quite confused on the whole matter, so any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated. Perhaps select() adds sockets for read operations that really aren't read operations? I'm pretty sure TCP does that for connection requests on a listening socket.

I'm using C++ in Visual Studio 2010 as my compiler and IDE. This is a console application with no MFC or any of that crap.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, -1 is `SOCKET_ERROR`, so no: -1 is never a normal value. The only other time I've seen this error is when you use `accept` on a TCP socket but then call `recv` on same socket you called `accept` on, rather than the return value of the `accept` call. Are you sure your `recvfrom` that fails is being called on the correct socket?

Comment: Oh. You're using windows 2000?